# MVC4, initiate work of 25 <a> links from the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

MVC4. Razor View has 100 links:  tags with "href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new { ...."
Each link points to the same "MyAction", but parameters values are different.
"MyAction" returns FileResult: downloads zip file onto users system.
So, user clicks on link -> user gets zip file downloaded on his system.
Now,
Instead of clicking on 25 links one-by-one to download 25 zip files,
user wants to click One button on that view that would download 25 zip files.

For a second day I am trying to find a way to accomplish this, but with no success.
-I was trying to find the way to send click event to 25 links on page: it looks like there is no way to make it work. 
- Now I am trying to find way to call "MyAction" 25 times with different parameters
Can somebody please help me to find a way to initiate work of 25 links from the code somehow ?
Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: give the links a special css class name, then use jquery to gather all matching elements with that class and perform the click.  However, either browsers or the web server tend to restrict the number of simultaneous requests and some downloads may time out depending on how large the files are.

Comment: I have tried these kind of approaches, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this:

```
  <div><a href="http://2i-it.com/download/file1.rar" class="auto-multi-click">File1</a></div>
  <div><a href="http://2i-it.com/download/file2.rar" class="auto-multi-click">File2</a></div>
  <div><a href="http://2i-it.com/download/file3.rar" class="auto-multi-click">File3</a></div>

  <a href="#" id="download-all">Download All</a>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     $(function () {
        $('#download-all').click(function () {
           $('.auto-multi-click').each(function () {
              var url = $(this).attr('href');
              window.open(url);
           });
        });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: In chrome, this will bring up all 3 downloads in the download window straight away. Just click on "Download All" to kick things off. If you make a jsfiddle I will post the full code there.

Comment: Thank you, I did try this, but, like with any other many approaches I have tried, only first zip file is loaded. Controller action "My Action" is called only once. In my case href is like: href="/Home/MyAction?parm1=10&amp;parm2=11&amp;parm3=True"

Comment: It's a url to call controller action, and does Not point to the file to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa nelly! "Clicking" 25 download links! Are you trying to kill your user? I have limited information to work with but if you can somehow "group" the links server side so they can be referenced, or maybe even pass in the Id's of all the files you want to download and pass them into an action method. Use a server-side zipping library and zip all the files together into 1 single zip and return that as the downloaded package. Please don't send 25 individual zips lol.

After a quick search, if you are using .net 4.5 then there is a nice library included you can use. Looks like you could even extract the 25 zips and then compress them all into a single zip file so they don't have a single zip file with 25 individual zips inside of it.

Either way, server-side is the way to go, I would think twice before sending a request for 25 download. This will hurt your users as well as your server.

.NET 4.5:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

3rd Party:
http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/

Comment: Than you for suggestion, but to have separate zip files is not my choice. Each zip file has specific name that specifies it's use later on. If I'll unzip and create only one zip, then somebody else will have to create those separate zips again. It's more about existing process that I can not change. And zipping zips is not the way to go.

Comment: In response, I would say zipping the zips then would be the best way. As stated by others another on here. Browsers have connection limits, 25 exceeds most browser limits I believe. Plus you run into the case of what if they hit download 2x+ now they have 50, 75, 100 downloads queued up. Good luck :)